# How to following websites (RSS) anonymously?

Tags: configuration, network-configuration, stream-isolation, isolation

This is a follow up question:

[IsolateDestAddr and IsolateDestPort usage?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12268/isolatedestaddr-and-isolatedestport-usage)

RSS desktop clients over tor are bad for anonymity. Very bad.

I'm not interested in following my favorite websites in a centralized way either(Feedly, Inoreader). DIY options like TinyRSS are no different than RSS desktop clients; all the data is fetched over the same IP.

So what's the solution? What's the most anonymous way to follow multiple websites? Checking each site individually seems painful.

Comment: You know what *actually* sucks for anonymity? Re-using emails across multiple identities ;) The other question wanted each feed to be unable to be linked to the other, not just unlinkable to them, this is different from anonymity. There is no existing client that I am aware of that will solve their problem. [TorBirdy](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/19031) and [Tails](https://labs.riseup.net/code/issues/11399) are working on using Thunderbird for an anonymous RSS feed reader which is probably where the best efforts are currently being made.

Comment: You know the answer: Checking each site individually.

Comment: What about using Live Bookmarks in the Tor Browser? Or am I completely missing the point?

Answer (score 1):

An RSS feed is no different than other web resorces: to browse it anonymously via Tor, connect to each site individually, one new circuit per site.

As it stands today, RSS feed aggregators just *aggregate* several feeds from a user-predefined list, retrieving it in the background and presenting it in an UI.

Taking e.g. [Tiny Tiny RSS](http://tt-rss.org), an OSS self-hosted PHP webapp, each feed in the list is checked in the background every *n* minutes for updates. From a network perspective, a single IP generates a recognisable pattern of traffic, either the native IP of the server, a proxy or an Tor exit node.

One may attain some level of obfuscation by having a very large set of feeds, so that one's fedlist does not have an unique, recognizable pattern. For example, by loading up as many as opml files one  finds on the net, or by having a large multiuser instance of tt-rss.

But for effectiveness, it depends on the risk model one has.